# Facebook C# MVC MVC3 store token alongside asp.net membership scenario

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-membership, facebook-c#-sdk

Hi does someone have a link or can offer some guidance on HOW the facebook C# SDK could be used to provide access credentials to facebook along side ASP.Net membership?

Basically what i would like to do is have some kind of connect button on my profile view that when clicked opens the facebook app authorization window, if the user signs in and agrees the facebook auth cookie is returned or accessible so i can store in locally in my DB.

I originally tried to figure out how to do this using dotnetopenauth about 9 months ago and eventually gave up. ANY help is appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it, but it shouldn't be too hard I think.

I'm assuming you already know how to "authenticate" users with Facebook using the C# SDK. At that very point where you consider them "authenticated" hook into it and perhaps use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() to manually authenticate the user from the default ASP.NET membership's perspective.